# Composer requires guzzlehttp/guzzle installation failed

Tags: laravel-5, guzzle

[Guzzle Installation Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di6CF.png)

> $ composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
> Using version ^7.4 for guzzlehttp/guzzle
> ./composer.json has been updated
> Running composer update guzzlehttp/guzzle
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.4, found guzzlehttp/guzzle[dev-master, 7.4.0, 7.4.1, 7.4.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

Problem 2
- laravel/passport is locked to version v7.5.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
- laravel/passport v7.5.1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~6.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.4).

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

I have been stuck on this problem with guzzle installation, can someone help me on this type of problem.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: feels like a repeated question check your composer.json to check your requirements for php, in laravel-5 as you have mentioned in the tag it works on with guzzle 6

Comment: `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle "^6.2.*"` requires php: >=5.5, check your requirements from [here](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle#6.2.1)

Answer (score 6):

composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle "^6.0" --with-all-dependencies

its for laravel 5.8